# Is $Y=Y(\omega) = \inf_{0 \leq t \leq 1}X_t(\omega) = 1_A(\omega)$ not measurable if $A \notin \mathcal{B}[0,1]?$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

Consider the probability space $([0,1], \mathcal{B}[0,1],\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $A \subset [0,1] $ and define

$ X_t(\omega) = 
\begin{cases} 0 \;\; if \; \; t = \omega \;, \; \omega \notin A \\
1 \; \; \; otherwise 
\end{cases} $

I would like to argue that all $X_t, t \in [0,1]$ are random variables, but that $Y=Y(\omega) = \inf_{0 \leq t \leq 1} X_t(\omega) = 1_A(\omega)$ is not measurable if $A \notin \mathcal{B}[0,1].$

I can't quite figure out how to solve this. Is $A$ open in $[0,1]$? If so, then $X_t(\omega)$ is not right continuous. For example, if $A = (0.5,0.6)$ then $X_{0.5}(\omega) = 0$ but $X_{0.5}+(\omega) = 1$ which violates $\lim_{y \to x, y > x} F(y) = F(x) $.

Comment: Your definition of $X_t$ is ambiguous.  Evidently you want to define a family of random variables $X_t$ indexed by the complement of a set $A,$ $X_t = \{I_{[0,1]\setminus \{t\}}\mid t\notin A\}.$  You intend for $A$ not to be *Lebesgue* measurable.  But then your question becomes a triviality, because the infimum of this family is the indicator of $A,$ which *by your assumptions* is not measurable, whence it's not a random variable.

Answer (score 2):

**Observation $1$**. Let $(X, \mathfrak A) $ be a measurable space and let $A\subset X. $ Then $\mathbf 1_A$ is $\mathfrak A$-measurable **if and only if** $A\in \mathfrak A. $

The proof is straightforward application of the definition of measurability of function. The conspicuous thing to notice is the set

$$\mathsf T:= \{x\in X:\mathbf 1_A(x)\leq \alpha\}\in \mathfrak A~~\forall~\alpha\in \mathbb R. \tag 1$$ Take $\alpha=0.5;$ then $\mathsf T = A^\complement\in \mathfrak A. $ This means $\mathsf T^\complement = A \in \mathfrak A. $

OP now can use this observation according to the necessity of the problem in hand.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration, *J. Yeh*, World Scientific Publishing, $2014;$ chapter $1, $ pp. $72-73.$

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question as written.  (Admittedly, it is weirdly formulated and difficult to interpret.)  Here, $\lambda$ explicitly is Lebesgue measure, which is the *completion* of the Borel measure.  There are Lebesgue-measurable sets that are not elements of $\mathfrak B[0,1].$

Comment: What I showed is that if an indicator function needs to be measurable, the corresponding set must belong to the underlying sigma algebra. I couldn't comprehend the specifics of OP. But I deem this statement does show OP's version is not a random variable.

Comment: The only way I can find to interpret the question in a way that does not trivialize it is to note there is a difference between the Borel sigma-algebra and the Lebesgue sigma-algebra.

Comment: Indeed OP had the tendency to make some confusing statements regarding this. And while I agree with your assessment, I deem this result would be helpful in whatever OP was venturing to. Unfortunately, OP never further clarified or responded.